# firebase-admin 5.12.0 fails to compile with tsc

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm using typescript environment to code the server on Node.js
When I try to compile the code, it's returning with an error:

```
> rimraf dist && tsc --outDir dist

node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.d.ts(18,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@google-cloud/storage'. '/<path-to-project>/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
```

I have the upgraded firebase-admin to the latest version (5.12.0)

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
```

I m running over the node version 9.5